# Kettle does not fetch data into dashboard table

Tags: kettle, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration, pentaho-cde

I'm trying to use kettle query in pentaho cde, I uploaded ktr file, then browse it from kettle query and determined the step of transformation but when I preview dashboard, table that use from kettle datasource is empty. What's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

There are two possibility
1) you must have to create a data source connection with the same in bi server as well, if not it will not work.
2) if you have uploaded a .ktr file in admin folder and if you will try to access it from some other user the also it will not work, for example : if you are running dashboard form admin user then file should be present in admin file , Suzy user then you must have to upload .ktr file in Suzy folder as well.

I am assuming your problem is related with second point.